# Got PN however application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification: not triggered when app icon is selected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm seeing a peculiar behavior with my push notification and was wondering if anyone has any advise on what I did wrong or should do.

I have my `application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:` written as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:YES];
}
```

As you can see, I'm not worried about the state of the app. I just want to log a message whenever I get a PN.

My setup is as per the documentation from Apple and I can receive push notifications.

The following are the expected behaviours when a PN comes in:

- **App is in the background and I click on the notification:** I can see the notification in notification center. Click on the notification, the app comes to the foreground and I can see the above method is called.
- **App is active and already in the foreground:** I can see the above method is called.

Now, the following is the peculiar behaviour I am seeing:

- **PN comes in. See it in the notifications, see the badge on the app icon. I click on the app icon - not the notification:** In this instance I found that the above method is **not** called. I was expecting it to be called...

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Is this what should happen? I couldn't see anything in the Apple documentation regarding this... Also, would there be a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

If the app was not running in background, but initially launched from the push notification and you have **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** implemented, you need to implement your code there:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
        if (userInfo != nil) {
            NSDictionary* apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
            NSString* custom = [userInfo objectForKey:@"yourCustomPushData"];
            // do something with it
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: no - I have the same problem, neither didfinishlaunchingwithoptions nor didreceiveremotenotification is called when the app is in background and push notification arrives and you return to the app tapping its icon

Answer (score 2):

I have the same behaviour. It drives me nuts but I think that's the way iOS works.

Below an excerpt from the apple documentation. This is regarding the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when the app is not running. It looks like it's the same for when the app is in background/didReceiveRemoteNotification.

"If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).

If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification . "
From: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Mrj's is not working in my case so I tried following option

If Application is not in background you should use following code

```
   //-------------- check notification when app is come to foreground after apllication get terminated ----------------//

UILocalNotification *localNotif =

[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (localNotif) {

    [self handleRemotNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]]; // private method


}
```